# What is the implication if I do not set a property = nil in viewDidUnload method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, properties

I have defined a property in my viewcontroller as follows

```
@interface QuestionAnswerViewController : UIViewController 
{
    Question *question;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Question *question;
```

and I synthesized the property in my .m file

```
@synthesize question;
```

Will there be any issues if I don't set 'self.question = nil' in my viewDidUnload method?

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    //Any issues if I don't set this?
    self.question = nil
}
```

Reason why I am asking this is because the 'question property' is actually passed in from another view controller. I realised that in the case of low memory, my view controller's view will be automatically unloaded, so if I set self.question=nil, I will lose the information on the current page (self.question becomes nil). Just want to confirm the repercussions in not setting a synthesized property to nil and if there are any other ways to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only release IBOutlets and those items that you can easily re-create on viewDidUnload.

If the view is unloaded, say automatically by a memory warning, any sub-components that are do not have their retains reduced will not be unload and less memory will be reclined that could be.  This ultimately may cause your app to be terminated due to insufficient memory.

In iOS IBOutlets are retained so setting their property to nil releases them.  Since the view that contains them is being unloaded these subviews have no reason to live, when the system reloads the view the subviews will also be reloaded at that time.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. So in my case, since self.question wasnt set in the viewDidload method, i should not set it to nil in the viewdidunload method. But what about the retain count for this property? How can i release it?

Comment: Rather, since it is not an IBOutlet it is totally up to you, it seems that in your case you do not want to set it to nil and loose it.  The object should be released in `dealloc`: `[question release];`.

Comment: Oh so does it mean that if the property is not an IOBOutlet, it is actually not required to set it to nil in view did unload? And just releasing it in dealloc will suffice (in terms of memory management)

Comment: Yes.  Actually there is no requirement, it is just good practice and can help in low memory situations when the view is unloaded.

Answer (score 1):

The implication is that those retained `subViews` of the `mainView` since they usually have a `retain` count of 2 for those declared as `retain`, one when it was set for the first time, and another one when it was added as a `subView`, when the `superView` is released the `retain` count will still be one.

Comment: The actual retain count is unknown, it is probably not 2.  What is true is that the property increased the retain count by one and we _assume_ that the view did as well.  The view will, if necessary, release all of it's retains and we need to release the one held by the property.